# iOS "Select | Select All | Paste" not working

Tags: ios, textbox

I'm using Ionic to build a hybrid app for both Android and iOS. I have a form in the app with four different text fields:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" ng-model="question.name" input-focus-parent required>
<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" ng-model="question.email" input-focus-parent required>
<input class="form-control" name="bookingNumber" type="text" ng-model="question.bookingNumber" input-focus-parent>
<textarea class="form-control textarea" name="question" type="text" rows="7" ng-model="question.text" input-focus-parent required></textarea>
```

If I type something in one of the fields and then press and hold on the text, in iOS I get this menu "Select | Select All | Paste". But I can't choose either Select or Select All (havn't tried Paste). Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't copy / paste in PhoneGap Ionic IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188234/cant-copy-paste-in-phonegap-ionic-ios)

Comment: also running into issue only with Select All, select seems to work fine

Comment: @matt.condit, did you ever find a solution for your problem? I have the exact same. Select works, but Select All does not.'