# ionic - Copy/paste in input field in iOS 10 not working

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ios10

As the title suggests, I am building a project with `ionic` and I am not able to copy/paste in the `input` fields on `iOS 10`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188234/cant-copy-paste-in-phonegap-ionic-ios) question, by applying these properties to the `css` the issue should be solved:

```
 input {
    user-select: auto !important;  
 }
```

but unluckily it is still not working. As also suggested by [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3793)  reference, it says that it may be caused by `$ionicLoading`, but I am not using it inside my controller.

Do you know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet, that's why I set the bounty :)

Comment: try double tap on the text field

Comment: Still nothing. The issue is that I can make the comic bubble show, but when I tap on "Paste" nothing happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was not able to understand your problem.

But if you want it to be really working, you can try it.

Install `cordova-plugin-clipboard`

```
var text = "Hello World!";

cordova.plugins.clipboard.copy(text);

cordova.plugins.clipboard.paste(function (text) { alert(text); });
```

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't get your issue:  "it does only if you copy text from the app, but what if you have to copy a text from a different app (like Gmail) and paste it?", It should work even if you copy the text from anywhere on the device. cordova.plugins.clipboard.paste(function (text) { alert(text); }); As far as I know, it should get the text what ever is copied from any app on the device. Could you please double check.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of just typing `user-select: auto !important;`

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188234/cant-copy-paste-in-phonegap-ionic-ios) answer try adding all css to the element instead of just that empty line that might not work on all browsers.

Here:

```
    -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
    -khtml-user-select: auto !important;
    -moz-user-select: auto !important;
    -ms-user-select: auto !important;
    -o-user-select: auto !important;
    user-select: auto !important;
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using an ion-spinner?

Just going off the following github thread:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3793

Comment: `$ionicLoading` is using an `ion-spinner`, but it is not used in the controller related to the login view

Comment: It might be worth removing that for a quick test if that's possible?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that but the problem still persists