# ionic iframe - Can't paste when long press on ios

Tags: html, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

iOS can not paste when long press but can copy.

I searched like below.

- [Can't copy / paste in PhoneGap Ionic IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188234/cant-copy-paste-in-phonegap-ionic-ios)
- [ionic - Copy/paste in input field in iOS 10 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279828/ionic-copy-paste-in-input-field-in-ios-10-not-working)

It not works well for me. 
I used `<iframe>` as `<ion-content>` child node. and both the copy and paste action happen on a html page embeded in iframe.

I add nothing to the `src/index.html`. I post the `home.html` and `home.scss`blow.

```css
page-home {

}

.selectable{
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
}

ion-content {
    background: none transparent;
}

iframe {
    background: none transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    position: absolute; 
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" >
  <iframe
      name="mainFrame" id="mainframe"
      src="http://180.168.168.210:8010/mobile/Login.html?"
      class="selectable">
  </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

And my ionic environment :

```
cli packages: 
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:
    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3

System:
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.1 
    ios-sim           : 5.0.13 
    Node              : v8.4.0
    npm               : 5.3.0 
    OS                : macOS Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

What should I do? I am confused to set which tag in which file.`iframe`, `ion-content` or `ion-app` in `src/index.html`?

Sorry to raise my question, but I really need your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

Make sure to add

'**overflow-scroll: true**' to the ion-content

Then you wrapped the text in a div with **class='selectable'**

then you made sure to add this to the selectable class.

```
-webkit-user-select: auto;
```

[here is working example](https://codepen.io/DaDanny/pen/ojQEox)

> Note: I haven't tested this on an actual device.

Good luck

Comment: The situation is text is not written in my ionic project, it is in a front-end html page. I use iframe to embed the page to my ionic project. Both the ionic project and front-end html page add the css, it is still not work.I can copy text whether set css or not, but I cant paste when long press on a `input/textarea` in the front-end html page on iOS device.Android works well